# IndexedDB database authentication - Security Options - Encryption / Hashing JavaScript HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, hash, indexeddb, password-encryption

I am trying to find ways to keep my HTML5 / JavaScript / VB website with an IndexedDB database secure, im new to authentication and new to IndexedDB.

How can I keep passwords secure? Is SHA an option?
I found this website and they seem to be using a passcode but I am not 100% sure on how to go about it, can anyone explain further?
Any tutorial in IndexedDB authentication would also be appriciated

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-html5/2Zsw0UO-MbM

Thank you

Comment: SHA* alone is not an option to hash passwords, because those functions are too fast, instead there are key-derivation functions like BCrypt and PBKDF2, which should be used to hash passwords.

Answer (score 5):

Why you need to keep password in client side?

Regarding caching database on client side, you do not need to encrypt it. Just keep it there as long as user don't logout. If user initiate logout, wipe out the database.

If the data is too sensitive like password, just don't save in client side.